# Reducing code duplication with Microsoft Graph Client Library

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on a class responsible for communicating with O365 using the Microsoft Graph Client Library. In each method, the call to NextPageRequest.GetAsync() is on a different type which also returns a different type, but otherwise the pagination logic is identical:

```cs
public async Task<List<Microsoft.Graph.User>> FindAllUsers()
{
    var usersFound = new List<Microsoft.Graph.User>();
    var usersPage = await GraphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
    usersFound.AddRange(usersPage);
    while (usersPage.NextPageRequest != null)
    {
        usersPage = await usersPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
        usersFound.AddRange(usersPage);
    }
    return usersFound;
}

public async Task<List<Microsoft.Graph.Group>> FindAllGroups()
{
    var groupsFound = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Group>();
    var groupsPage = await GraphClient.Groups.Request().GetAsync();
    groupsFound.AddRange(groupsPage);
    while (groupsPage.NextPageRequest != null)
    {
        groupsPage = await groupsPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
        groupsFound.AddRange(groupsPage);
    }
    return groupsFound;
}

public async Task<List<Microsoft.Graph.User>> FindGroupMembers(string groupId)
{
    var usersFound = new List<Microsoft.Graph.User>();
    var membersPage = await GraphClient.Groups[groupId].Members.Request().GetAsync();
    usersFound.AddRange(membersPage.Where(d => d.ODataType.Equals("#microsoft.graph.user")).Cast<Microsoft.Graph.User>());
    while (membersPage.NextPageRequest != null)
    {
        membersPage = await membersPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
        usersFound.AddRange((List<Microsoft.Graph.User>)membersPage);
    }
    return usersFound;
}
```

I would like to write generic method to reduce duplication, but in each of the above methods, the return type of GetAsync is a different interface that defines its own NextPageRequest property on itself. This makes it impossible to tell the generic method what specific type it will need to call NextPageRequest on so that the method can compile.

Is there a way to improve upon this, or do I just need to accept the duplicated logic for each query type I want to implement?

Comment: You could write a non generic method that takes the pagination object and determines the NextPageRequest object and call that from your generic method.

Comment: It looks like a good place to use C# *dynamic* keyword.

Comment: That is an interesting idea @johnnyjob, I've never used dynamic before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Microsoft Graph API architects, it looks like we can only get rid of such sort of redundancy either by using reflection or dynamics. Since dynamics, in theory, should provide better performance, here's a version of sample code based on them:

```
private void ProcessAllResultPages<TResult, TItem>(IBaseRequest request,
                                                   Action<TResult> processorDelegate)
                                                   where TResult : ICollectionPage<TItem>
{
    do
    {
        Task<TResult> task = ((dynamic)request).GetAsync();
        processorDelegate(task.Result); // This will implicitly call Wait() on the task.
        request = ((dynamic)task.Result).NextPageRequest;
    } while (request != null);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionRequest request = graphServiceClient.Groups.Request().
                                                                         Filter(...).
                                                                         Select(...).
                                                                         Top(pageSize);
ProcessAllResultPages<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage, Group>(request,
    result =>
    {
        // Process page results here.
    });
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. I didn't end up implementing it due to concerns around understandably issues for other developers down the road but it does address the question as presented.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to reduce duplication of code:

```
        public async Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync<T>(IBaseRequest baseRequest)
        where T : DirectoryObject
    {
        List<T> pagedItems = new();

        try
        {
            var pageOfItems = await ((dynamic)baseRequest).GetAsync();

            pagedItems.AddRange(pageOfItems);
            while (pageOfItems.NextPageRequest != null)
            {
                pageOfItems = await pageOfItems.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                pagedItems.AddRange(pageOfItems);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
        return pagedItems;
    }
```

And then use it with:

```
            var result = await GetAllAsync<Microsoft.Graph.Group>(_graphServiceClient.Groups.Request());

            var result = await GetAllAsync<Microsoft.Graph.User>(_graphServiceClient.Users.Request());
```